# Como resolver o problema do FusionCharts no Google Chrome?

Tags: php

Estou com um problema em minha página que contém gráficos da biblioteca `FusionCharts`.
No `IE` funciona normalmente, no Chrome da minha máquina também funciona, porém, tenho outra máquina que no lugar do gráfico aparece **download failed**, no entanto, na mesma máquina roda normalmente no `IE`.

Segue o código da página:

```
$strXML = "<graph caption='ABSENTEEISM BY SECTOR' bgColor='000000,000000' basefontcolor='#ffffff'
          basefontsize='21' basefont='Calibri' theme='fint' borderthickness='0' valueonright='1' canvasbgcolor='#000000' xAxisName='' yAxisName='Quantity of MOs'>";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    //echo $result['HORA']."<br>";      

    $strXML .= "<set label='".$result[0]."' value='".$result[1]."' color='".$color."' />";
}

$geral = mysql_query("select round((falta/total)*100) as total, round((gestante/total)*100) as gravida, round((pcd/total)*100) as pcd from
(select count(*) as falta from prom.absenteismo where observacao not in ('PCD','AFASTADO','FERIAS','GESTANTE')) as tb1,
(select count(*) as pcd from prom.absenteismo where observacao in ('PCD')) as tb2,
(select count(*) as total from prom.absenteismo) as tb3,
(select count(*) as gestante from prom.absenteismo where observacao in ('GESTANTE')) as tb4");

$total = mysql_fetch_row($geral);

$strXML .=  "</graph>";
include("FusionCharts.php");
echo "<center>";
echo renderChart("Charts/Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "chart1", 1200, 400);
echo "</center>";
```